# JSON array syntax. Are the curly brackets (object syntax) strictly necessary?

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible for a json string to include only square brackets ? For ex. :

```
[["state","accepted"],["r_by_uid",1]]
```

I get unexpected character error from parsing that string ... (long time since i worked on this script and i think it worked before ) .

Parsing the json string will allways make an object from the string ? or is it possible to parse the string into an array ?

Basically i just want to parse the string into an array , not an object .
I googled some examples but couldnt find any example that is using only square brackets.

As requested here is the tag that holds the json string :

```
<button data-fproc='[["state","accepted"],["r_by_uid","1"]]' class="request_state_button">
```

Comment: Paste the html as it appears in view source, like: `data-fproc="example"`

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/7ARmP/1/ Review any possible differences such as calling `.attr` when the element doesn't exist

Comment: @Esailija there must be something wrong with the jquery then ... anyway ty to all who helped , basically the question has a valid answer , i'll find the problem eventually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Curly brackets are not strictly necessary.

`[["state","accepted"],["r_by_uid",1]]` is valid JSON.

A JSON text can be an object or an array.

See http://json.org/ and the *JSON Grammar* section in https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt

You can validate your JSON at http://jsonlint.com/

---

In Javascript, [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) returns an array:

```
JSON.parse('[["state","accepted"],["r_by_uid",1]]')
// result [["state", "accepted"], ["r_by_uid", 1]]
```

Notice that Arrays are also objects in Javascript.

It works with [`jQuery.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) too:

```
jQuery.parseJSON('[["state","accepted"],["r_by_uid",1]]')
// result [["state", "accepted"], ["r_by_uid", 1]]
```

Comment: But i get JSON.parse: unexpected character error , i dont know why . Using jquery function for parsing

Comment: It works with jQuery.parseJSON(), too. How are you calling it ?

Comment: $.parseJSON($(this).attr('data-fproc')) , da-fproc being the json string in the question , copied from the html source

Comment: ill check the jquery , or use some other parser . At least i know the json string is ok

Comment: `$(this).attr('data-fproc')` may already return the parsed JSON, as an Array. You don't need parseJSON :)

Comment: @arnaud576875 that's `$(this).data("fproc")`. `.attr` doesn't attempt to parse as JSON

Answer (score 1):

Probably this will explain your problem:

```
 var aAsArray = [["state","accepted"],["r_by_uid",1]];
 var aAsString = '[["state","accepted"],["r_by_uid",1]]';

 ​JSON.parse(aAsArray);​​​    //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ....
 JSON.parse(aAsString);
```