# Handle raw JSON string with node and express

Tags: json, node.js, express

I have a really simple endpoint defined in NodeJS using Express:

```
router.put("/test", this.test.bind(this));

public test(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    console.log(req.body);
}
```

The endpoint is working correctly if I `PUT` the following JSON body:

```
{
    "name": "something"
}
```

However, if I use a JSON body without curly brackets (which is totally valid) like this:

```
"something"
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)
```

Content-Type in both cases is `application/json`.

Why are these raw JSON strings not getting accepted and how can I solve this?

Comment: Just a string without curly brackets is by no means valid JSON

Comment: @PatrickHund It is, check [https://jsonlint.com/](https://jsonlint.com/) and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414523/json-array-syntax-are-the-curly-brackets-object-syntax-strictly-necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414523/json-array-syntax-are-the-curly-brackets-object-syntax-strictly-necessary)

Comment: Ok, I stand corrected